# Printing patterns using arrays in c

Tags: c

The problem is to print this pattern:

```
5555555555
5444444445
5433333345
5432222345
5432112345
5432112345
5432222345
5433333345
5444444445
5555555555
```

This is my code:

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
    int i,k,j,n,p;
    printf("enter the no  :  ");
    scanf("%d",&n);
    p = n;
    k = 0;
    int a[2*n][2*n];

    while (p>=1)
    {
        for(i=0+k;i<2*n-k;i++)
        {
            for(j=0+k;j<2*n-k;j++)
            {
                if(i == 2*n-k||i == k||j == k||j == 2*n-k)
                {
                    a[i][j]=p;
                }
                else
                {
                    a[i][j]= 8;
                }
            }
            printf("\n");
        }
        k++,p--;
    }
    for(i=0;i<2*n;i++)
    {
        for(j=0;j<2*n;j++)
        {
            printf("%d",a[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }

    return 0;
}
```

The result I get is:

```
5555555555
5444444448 
5433333388 
5432222888 
5432118888 
5432188888 
5432888888 
5438888888 
5488888888 
5888888888
```

Comment: I suggest you to read the [tutorial](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/). It contains invaluable advice on how to solve this problem.

Comment: Why do you have `a[i][j]= 8;`? There's nothing in the problem about printing 8.

Comment: @Mohammed Abdurrasheed To output the pattern an array is not required.

Comment: it is to avoid garbage values however the that doesnt effect the actual code the value 8 should change later

Comment: In your post I see a problem statement without an actual problem stated.  I see an approach that results in an ordered list, So, what exactly is the problem with the approach you are using.  i.e. is the output you are displaying not correct?  Where in your code do you think the problem lies?, ... etc.  It would be good to read _[this](https://stackoverflow.com/tour)_.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is overly complex. You should utilize the symmetry. Replace you while-loop with this code.

```
// Because of symmetry, both i and j can loop to n instead of 2*n
for(i=0; i<n; i++) {
    p = n;
    for(j=0; j<n; j++) {
        // Assign four cells at once due to both horizontal and vertical symmetry
        a[i][j] = a[i][2*n-j-1] = a[2*n-i-1][j] = a[2*n-i-1][2*n-j-1] = p;

        if(j<i)
            p--;
    }
}
```